# SQL Server Select with different where conditions for different field values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, conditional-statements, where-clause

I want to select data from my table `offer` which has a field called `type` and I need to apply different conditions to each type.

The code may look like this:

```
select * from offer where 
if type = 1 then apply condition_1,
else if type = 2 then apply condition_2 and condition_3,
else if type = 3 then apply condition_4,
```

So how can I achieve that?

Comment: it would help if you could post what the conditions are..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from offer
where (type =1 and condition_1 )
or ( type = 2 and condition_2 and condition_3 ) 
or (type = 3 and condition_3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from offer 
where CASE WHEN [type] = 1 then condition_1
           WHEN [type] = 2 then (condition_2 and condition_3)
           WHEN [type] = 3 then apply condition_4 END`
```